# React: How to pass props functions for a mapped component?

Tags: reactjs, forms, dynamic, submit, react-component

I am making a dynamic table with a row component which further serves as a component for a Form.

My question is:

**How to pass functions as props for a mapped component and get back the input value array from the component?**

I have a row component with three select elements as shown here.

[image]

The code for this component is here.

```
import Select from "react-select";
import { Row, Col, Button, Container, Form } from "react-bootstrap";
import React, { useState } from "react";
import { useEffect } from "react";

const baseurl = "http://localhost:5000/api";

const Dselect = (props) => {
  const [pdtCodeOptions, setPdtCodeOptions] = useState([]);
  const [catListOptions, setCatListOptions] = useState([]);
  const [pdtListOptions, setPdtListOptions] = useState([]);

  const [selectedCat, setSelectedCategory] = useState();
  const [selectedPcode, setSelectedPCode] = useState();
  const [selectedPName, setSelectedPName] = useState();

  const [inputs, setInputs] = useState({
    pdt_code: "",
    pdt_category: "",
    pdt_name: "",
  });

  useEffect(() => {
    const fetchCat = async (e) => {
      const res = await fetch(`${baseurl}/cat`);
      const cList = await res.json();

      let catOpt = [];
      for (let i = 0; i < cList.length; i++) {
        catOpt.push({ label: cList[i].category, value: cList[i].category });
      }
      setCatListOptions(catOpt);
    };

    const fetchPdtCode = async (e) => {
      const res = await fetch(`${baseurl}/pdtlist`);
      const pList = await res.json();
      const pdtList = [];
      for (let i = 0; i < pList.length; i++) {
        pdtList.push({ label: pList[i].pdt_id, value: pList[i].pdt_id });
      }
      setPdtCodeOptions(pdtList);
    };

    fetchCat();
    fetchPdtCode();
  }, []);

  console.log(inputs);

  const getPdtDetails = async (e) => {
    const pdtID = e.value;

    const res = await fetch(`${baseurl}/details`, {
      method: "POST",
      headers: { "Content-Type": "application/json" },
      body: JSON.stringify({ data: pdtID }),
    });
    const detList = await res.json();

    const pdt_name = detList[0].pdt_name;
    const category = detList[0].category;

    setSelectedCategory({ label: category, value: category });
    setSelectedPName({ label: pdt_name, value: pdt_name });
  };

  const updateList = async (e) => {
    const catVal = e.value;
    console.log(e);

    const res = await fetch(`${baseurl}/pdtList`, {
      method: "POST",
      headers: { "Content-Type": "application/json" },
      body: JSON.stringify({ data: catVal }),
    });
    const pdtList = await res.json();

    const catPdtList = [];
    for (let i = 0; i < pdtList.length; i++) {
      catPdtList.push({
        label: pdtList[i].pdt_name,
        value: pdtList[i].pdt_name,
      });
    }
    setPdtListOptions(catPdtList);
  };

  const getPdtcode = async (e) => {
    const pdtName = e.value;
    const category = inputs.pdt_category;
    const data = { category: category, pdtName: pdtName };

    const res = await fetch(`${baseurl}/pdtCode`, {
      method: "POST",
      headers: { "Content-Type": "application/json" },
      body: JSON.stringify(data),
    });
    const code = await res.json();
    console.log(code);
    setSelectedPCode({ label: code, value: code });
  };

  const changeHandler = (e, opt) => {
    console.log(e);
    console.log(opt);
    const name = opt.name;
    const value = e.value;
    setInputs((values) => ({ ...values, [name]: value }));
  };

  return (
    <Row className="mt-3">
      {props.r + 1}
      <Col lg={3} md={3} xs={3}>
        <Select
          name="pdt_code"
          options={pdtCodeOptions}
          placeholder="Select product Code"
          value={selectedPcode}
          onChange={(e, opt) => {
            setSelectedPCode(selectedPcode);
            changeHandler(e, opt);
            getPdtDetails(e);
          }}
        />
      </Col>

      <Col lg={3} md={3} xs={3}>
        <Select
          options={catListOptions}
          name="pdt_category"
          placeholder="Category"
          value={selectedCat}
          onChange={(e, opt) => {
            setSelectedCategory(selectedCat);
            changeHandler(e, opt);
            updateList(e);
          }}
        />
      </Col>

      <Col lg={3} md={3} xs={3}>
        <Select
          name="pdt_name"
          options={pdtListOptions}
          onChange={(e, opt) => {
            setSelectedPName(selectedPName);
            changeHandler(e, opt);
            getPdtcode(e);
          }}
          value={selectedPName}
          placeholder="Select product Name"
        />
      </Col>

      <Col lg={2} md={2} xs={2}>
        <Button
          type="button"
          onClick={(e) => props.onDelete(props.r)}
          className="btn btn-secondary"
        >
          Del
        </Button>
      </Col>
    </Row>
  );
};

export default Dselect;
```

Then I created a table component to dynamically add/delete rows of the above component.
(I had some issues while writing this code. It was asked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72891475/react-deleting-dynamically-added-row-removes-every-rows-below-it).
Current code goes here.

```
import React from "react";
import Dselect from "../components/dSelect";
import { Row, Col, Form, Button } from "react-bootstrap";
import { useState, useEffect } from "react";

const TableShow = () => {
  const [idCount, setIdCount] = useState(0);
  const [rows, setRows] = useState([{ id: idCount }]);

  const delRow = (index) => setRows(rows.filter((row) => row.id !== index));

  const addRow = () => {
    const newId = idCount + 1;
    setIdCount(newId);
    setRows([...rows, { id: newId }]);
  };

  return (
    <div>
        <Button className="mt-3 btn-sm btn-info" onClick={addRow}>
          Add rows
        </Button>
        {rows.map((row) => (
          <Dselect onDelete={delRow} key={row.id} r={row.id} />
        ))}
    </div>
  );
};

export default TableShow;
```

I added this table component inside a form. I am trying to submit the form. But I couldn't get the value of the above input fields.

Code for my form so far is as below.

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import { Container, Button, Form, Row, Col } from "react-bootstrap";
import Dselect from "../components/dSelect";
import TableShow from "./tablePage";

const baseurl = "http://localhost:5000/api";

const FormSubmit = () => {
  const [inputs, setInputs] = useState({
    instruct_date: "",
    user_name: "",
  });  

const [rowInput, setRowInput] = useState([]);

  const changeHandler = (event) => {
    const name = event.target.name;
    const value = event.target.value;

    setInputs((values) => ({ ...values, [name]: value }));
  };

  const SubmitHandler = async (event) => {
    event.preventDefault();

    await fetch(`${baseurl}/submit/instruct`, {
      method: "POST",
      headers: { "Content-Type": "application/json" },
      body: JSON.stringify({
        input1: inputs,
        input2: rowInput,
      }),
    });
  };

  return (
    <Container>
      <h4> FORM </h4>
      <Form>
        <Row>
          <Col l={4} md={4} xs={6}>
            <div className="form-group form-inline">
              <label>Date</label>
              <input
                type="date"
                className="form-control"
                name="instruct_date"
                value={inputs.instruct_date}
                onChange={changeHandler}
              />
            </div>
          </Col>
          <Col l={4} md={4} xs={6}>
            <div className="form-group form-inline">
              <label>Name</label>
              {/* <OptionsTeam /> */}
              <input
                type="text"
                className="form-control"
                name="team_name"
                value={inputs.user_name}
                onChange={changeHandler}
              />
            </div>
          </Col>
        </Row>
        <TableShow />
        <Button className="my-3" onClick={SubmitHandler}>
          Submit
        </Button>
      </Form>
    </Container>
  );
};

export default FormSubmit;
```

I tried to get values in "rowInput". But I couldn't.

Comment: please provide codesandbox link

Comment: https://codesandbox.io/s/component-cchild-props-cei8r7?file=/src/App.js

here is the codesandbox